# I have a Unity WebGL game uploaded. Is it possible to manually create a persistent directory in /idbfs inside IndexedDB?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl, indexeddb

In the Unity project, I attached a script in an empty game object, and the code is demonstrated below:
Is it possible to create a persistent directory myself?

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        GetDefaultDirectory();
        CreateCustomDirectory();
    }

    // It returns "idbfs/" following with a random hash, such as "66ae5aa9b53f4a794ca331d30d2cb976".
    public void GetDefaultDirectory()
    {
        Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath);
    }

    // Manually create a directory
    // This can be created but will be flushed away after the page is reloaded.
    public void CreateCustomDirectory()
    {
#if UNITY_WEBGL
        Directory.CreateDirectory("idbfs/abcdef");
#endif
    }
}
```

And here's what the IndexedDB looks like. Only a random hash is shown here and my custom directory "idbfs/abcdef" won't be shown. But it did exist as I checked using Debug.Log.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In WebGL the path is passed through md5, that's why you can't recognize your directory name.

Here is the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)